# CSS selector for the first element after another not being siblings

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I wonder if this is even possible. With this html:

```
<h1></h1>
<form>
    <label><input type="text"></label>
    <label><input type="text"></label>
    <label><input type="text"></label>
</form>
```

I know I can do:

```
label:first-child{}
```

but I wonder if it is possible to select only the first label preceded by a h1 that is not at the same level with + or ~ or something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the below selector:

```
h1 + form > label:first-child {
   /* some properties here */
}
```

So the above selector will select the `form` element which is a sibling of `h1` and than it gets in and selects the first direct `label` element and hence am using `>`

You can safely get rid of the `>` if you are sure that you might not have any further nested `label` elements inside your `form` element.

---

Note that this is a very generic tag selector, I will suggest you to wrap your elements inside a wrapper element and give it a `class` say `form-wrapper` and modify your selector like

```
.form-wrapper h1 + form > label:first-child {
  /* some stuff */
}
```

Comment: I agree with you on that but in this case the page won't have much more than a form

Comment: @Mr. Alien  Please do you think you could help me with this question http://goo.gl/Yl5qIi

Comment: @Axel paste the original link, won't click on the minified one

Comment: Sorry about that. This is the original one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054526/asp-net-gridview-overflows-parent-div-when-it-has-lots-of-columns

Answer (score 1):

```css
h1 + form label:first-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>H1</h1>
<form>
  <label>First</label>  
  <label>Second</label>  
  <label>Third</label>  
</form>

<h2>H2</h2>
<form>
  <label>First</label>  
  <label>Second</label>  
  <label>Third</label>  
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the next sibling using `+` and then use the descendent selector to target the label.

```css
h1 + form label:first-child {
  padding-right: 120px;
}
```

```html
<h1></h1>
<form>
  <label>
    <input type="text">
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="text">
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="text">
  </label>
</form>
```