# Asp.net gridview overflows parent div when it has lots of columns

Tags: css, asp.net, gridview, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a gridview fit inside a div using relative widths , but it always breaks out its parent container when it has too many columns.

I know that using a fixed width like this would apparently solve the problem, but if I re-size the window a little bit, the gridview will overflow again as it has a specific width.

```
<div style="overflow: scroll; width: 1000px; Height: 300px;">
   <asp:GridView id="GridView1" runat="server"  />
</div>
```

Is there any way I can specify a relative with to the container and use overflow:scroll as well so that if I re-size the window the gridview will re-size with its container.

Here's a few images of what is happening using a `width:100%`
One thing that I noticed here is that when the window is 100% zoom the gridview overflows its container but as I decrease the zoom the problem seems to disappear. Really strange :S

I'd really appreciate if someone could help here.

**100% zoom**

[image]

**75% zoom**

[image]

**65% zoom**

[image]

Comment: So you want a responsive grid?

Comment: @Mr.Alien No, not necessarily. I just don't want the gridview to overflow its container. Please see my answer, perhaps you know why I got this weird problem. Thanks

Comment: Lil caught up with some work, give me time till tomorrow morning, will read it in detail and reply you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but I've got really tired of trying to find a CSS solution.
So I ended up using jQuery like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            bindEvents();
        });
        function bindEvents() {
            $(window).on('resize', function () {
                adjustNewSize();
            });
        }
        function adjustNewSize() {

            var parentContainer = $("#divParentContainer");
            var gridContainer = $("#divGridContainer");           
            $(parentContainer).width("80%");        
            $(gridContainer).width(($(parentContainer).width()));

        }       

    </script>
```

And the below the `Toolkit:ToolkitScriptManager` the following script

```
<Toolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="YourToolKitID" runat="server">
    </Toolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

        prm.add_endRequest(function () {
            bindEvents();
        });
    </script>
```

This works great on IE, Mozilla and Chrome, but the minimize/maximize buttons of the browser sometimes don't seem to fire the resize event. I say, **seem**, because the event is actually fired but the divs don't adjust as they do when I change the size of the browser manually.

Answer (score 1):

You may try `overflow-x: auto`

```
<div style="overflow-x: auto; width: 1000px; Height: 300px;">
   <asp:GridView id="GridView1" runat="server"  />
</div>
```

But from your screenshots it seems that not only the grid but the form div and some other div above form are also overflowing. In that case you may set the `overflow-x` property of parent div accordingly.

Comment: haraman thank for your answer. Sadly I've already tried what you suggested and it works at first sight, but if by any chance the user shrinks the browser, the gridview will remain with its original 1000px wide causing it to overflow its parent div again. P.S. If I remove the gridview I can stretch out/shrink the browser and the content will fit accordingly as I'm using relative width for all the divs :(

Comment: @Axel In that case it would be better if you post more code pertaining to the parent elements / controls, column structure and css, if used any. As a quick debug option you may try Inspect element tool in Google Chrome or FireBug in FireFox to monitor the css being applied to the output

Answer (score 0):

HAve you tried setting the width as % in place of pixel...
ex:- width: 90% 
when we set width a pixel it will be a fixed size  but setting it as percentage changes width according to the width of container